# how to add nfc_extras to android project using reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, nfc

I want to use nfc_extras in my android project to use card emulation capability of my phone. I know there are two ways to do that; either by creating a jar file in Android source or using reflection. I'd prefer to go through the second one though. How to do that through reflection? How I can use reflection to take advantage of nfc_extras in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Nikolay Elenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242930/nikolay-elenkov)'s blog at http://nelenkov.blogspot.nl/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html for an in-depth tutorial on how to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. However, I've already read that blog, although it is great, my problem is how to add nfc_extras.jar file to my android project. I've found a com.android.nfc_extras.jar file, it was published 7 months ago though. So I'm not sure if it works fine. And I've also visited [http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com$java$ext@com.google.android$android@2.3.7_r1@META-INF$MANIFEST.MF?av=o#%3CMain%3E]      I couldn't get how I should extract a .jar file from the codes represented there,too. Could you please guide me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you use reflection, you do not need the jar file... It is already on your device.

Comment: Thank you very much.This is exactly what I needed to know. I knew how to use reflection in code, but I was wondering how the nfc_extras is loaded to the project!!

Comment: One more problem is, as far as I've understood, the signature attribute in nfcee_access.xml file is the one the application is signed with. I tried to sign one of my applications just to see what is created. What I saw was just a keystore, however I don't know how to use that and to extract the required signature from it to use in nfcee_access.xml file. I'm new to this field so excuse me for my immature questions. I'm waiting for your generosity anyway!

Comment: You can add a debug statement to the nfcee_access.xml file (don't know the exact syntax by heart). It will print the signature from any application trying to access card emulation, ready for copy an paste into the xml file. That is the easiest way to obtain the required signature.

Comment: Thanks.As you know modifying nfcee_access.xml needs root access to the phone which can be risky,especially for me, as I'm using a customized phone and I'm not sure what happens when I try to root it!So I was wondering that do we have to deal with this file even if we use Android source code and go through that way?Because if we don't, then dealing with the source code might be more reliable.

Comment: You don't need to root it (in the sense that you would be installing SuperSU or something like it). You copy the xml file off the device and modify it, then mount the system partition in r/w mode and write it back and reboot to make the changes take effect (and mount the system image r/o). Or, if that is more convenient for you, modify the file before creating the system image from source code.

Comment: As a result, in both ways we have to modify nfcee_access.xml file;And, SuperSU requires a rooted device itself based on [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en].Thanks for your great help